# Android NDEF NFC Payload

Tags: android, nfc

I am using NDEF nfc cards and my application is reading the data in the card. Everything works great. However as part of the payload I am also getting the language type in it.

```
If the NFC string is "Hello"

String text = new String(records.get(k).getNdefRecord().getPayload());

Output is "enHello"
```

I am sure I can use substring to remove the first two characters but is there a way to get Payload message only without getting the language string in it?

Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

What's your strategy for converting from a byte array to a String?  There's more data returned in `getPayload()` than simply the text you want to read.  [This link](https://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/NFC) has a breakdown of the protocol, plus there's another link or two on SO [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917567/strange-character-on-android-ndef-record-payload?rq=1) that explains how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a library called [NDEF Tools for Android](https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) for reading and writing high-level record representation from the basic NdefMessage/NdefRecord in Android. See the [Text Record](https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/ndeftools/src/org/ndeftools/wellknown/TextRecord.java) for some pointers.